# start env with new line (no par)

Tags: line-breaking, environments

I have custom enviroment. I would like my env starts (simply) with new line because i have custom length for `\parskip` and `\parindent`. How can i adjust my env to to start with new line and end up with one and avoid code like the next one?

```
    \\
    \begin{envenv}
    ...
    \end{envenv}
    \\
```

Comment: you never want `\\ ` just use `\par` (and add a vskip to adjust for `\parskip` if that is needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case you may simply need

[image]

where the *aa aa* text in the environment is not offset by the 1cm paragraph space.  In more complicated contexts you may need to make the negative spacing conditional on some tests, but the above is simply

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\parskip{1cm}

\newenvironment{envenv}
 {\par\addvspace{-\parskip}\itshape}
 {\par\addvspace{-\parskip}}
\begin{document}



zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 

zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
\begin{envenv}
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 
aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa aa 
\end{envenv}
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 

zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz zzz 
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a problem: if i write one env next to other i get one env other another.

Comment: @user6786661 try now (`\addvspace` not `\vspace`)